# MySQL memory usage is too high - OOM

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.6, memory

Im using 32vCPU and 120GB VM for Mysql 5.6.

1. it's a dedicated MySQL server.
2. 15000 IOPS SSD disk.
3. Total database
   size 40G

This server was working fine for a couple of months. Memory usage is never crossed 60GB.

But a few days back the mysql process killed due to OOM. After restart memory usage is fine, but its gradually increasing within 6 to hrs it'll reach the maximum limit and killed by OOM Killer.

After installing the mysql, I used percona configuration wizard to generate the my.cnf file.

#### Here are the important parameters:

```
# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 5000
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 4096
table-open-cache               = 50

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 90G
```

The last downtime happened yesterday. I have verified that the InnoDB buffer never crossed 30GB for the whole day.

## Buffer Pool usage

[image]

## Memory used:

The both highlighted points are the maximum limit.
[image]

## InnoDB IO

[image]

## Mysql client thread activity:

[image]

## Temo Objects:

[image]

## Mysql Internal memory

[image]

From a shell script:

```
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                          key_buffer_size |          32.000 MB |
|                         query_cache_size |           0.000 MB |
|                  innodb_buffer_pool_size |       92160.000 MB |
|          innodb_additional_mem_pool_size |           8.000 MB |
|                   innodb_log_buffer_size |           8.000 MB |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                              BASE MEMORY |       92208.000 MB |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                         sort_buffer_size |           0.250 MB |
|                         read_buffer_size |           0.125 MB |
|                     read_rnd_buffer_size |           0.250 MB |
|                         join_buffer_size |           0.250 MB |
|                             thread_stack |           0.250 MB |
|                        binlog_cache_size |           0.031 MB |
|                           tmp_table_size |          32.000 MB |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                    MEMORY PER CONNECTION |          33.156 MB |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                     Max_used_connections |               1399 |
|                          max_connections |               5000 |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                              TOTAL (MIN) |      138593.594 MB |
|                              TOTAL (MAX) |      257989.250 MB |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

### I just wanted to know that, InnoDB never crossed >30, but how mysql used all the memory?

Comment: This is dedicated for mysql, other services.

Comment: I have verified that global buffers are 96GB

Comment: I'm facing something similar, though with a 8GB server.  What's RSS/VSZ reported by `ps aux`?  Can you add the message reported by OOM killer?  As configured, you could need up to 256GB to support his config.  it's probably unlikely you'll have 5000 connections using a 32MB temp table... but it could happen :)

Comment: Hi Kevin, I fixed this issue by reducing the max_prepare_statement_count value. Earlier it was the max value.

Comment: Here is my explanation for mysql memory consumption. I hope it will be useful: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/256135/7895

Answer (score 0):

5,000 connections is a LOT, there are a lot of different memory buffers allocated on a per connection basis. Just your max_connections * tmp_table_size is enough to overwhelm your server's memory if many of your connections start using a lot of large implicitly created temporary tables.

Here is a reasonably comprehensive equation from my [MySQL memory tuning article](https://shatteredsilicon.net/mariadb-performance-tuning-and-mysql-performance-tuning/):

```
SELECT (
       (
           @@binlog_file_cache_size +
           @@innodb_buffer_pool_size +
           @@innodb_log_buffer_size +
           @@key_buffer_size +
           @@query_cache_size +
           ( @@max_connections *
               ( @@binlog_cache_size +
                 @@binlog_stmt_cache_size +
                 @@bulk_insert_buffer_size +
                 @@join_buffer_size +
                 @@max_allowed_packet +
                 @@read_buffer_size +
                 @@read_rnd_buffer_size +
                 @@sort_buffer_size +
                 @@thread_stack +
                 @@tmp_table_size
               )
           ) +
           ( @@slave_parallel_threads * 
             ( @@slave_parallel_max_queued )
           ) +
           ( @@open_files_limit * 1024)
       ) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) AS max_memory_GB;
```

Adjust those, including your max_connections until the value output by this query reasonably fits into your memory.

Disclosure: I wrote the referenced article.