# my.cnf for 16 GB Ram Server [MariaDB]

Tags: mysql, my.cnf, mariadb-10.1

I am very new to this stuff. I just wanted to ask if somebody has a good my.cnf for my MariaDB database because every time i have more than  1000 connections to my website it starts to have hight load time up to 16 Seconds under this value it loads instand.

My mysql settings are very default i only changed the max_connections.

```
max_connections        = 10000
```

Server Specs:

- CPU: Intel i7-4790K 4c / 8t 4GHz
- RAM: 16 GB DDR3
- Debian 9
- PHP Version 7.0.33
- Apache 2.4.25
- MariaDb 10.1.41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_connections` depends on RAM because each connection uses RAM for read/join/sort buffers. You can not set `max_connections` arbitrary high. In general the RAM consumption can be represented that way:

```
+------+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|  OS  | MyISAM/InnoDB buffers | Connections buffers | Third party |
|      |                       +---------------------+             |
|      |                       | | | | | | | ...     |             |
+------+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------+
```

- Host's OS need some RAM for the proper operation - usually 1-2GB+.
- Third party services (apache/php/etc) requirements should be
  considered.
- DB engines are used RAM for caching. MyISAM caches
  indexes only while InnoDB caches both data and indexes.
- All active connections consumes a lot of RAM.

For maximum performance InnoDB should have `innodb pool` big enough to fit all the tables and their indexes in the RAM. `max_connections` should be tuned along with the `read_buffer`, `join_buffer` and `sort_buffer` values.

But the main attention should be paid to the queries optimization. You can't get a good overall peformance if the single query is slow. Even if you have the host with 256-512 GB of RAM it can be slow if the frequenlty executed queries are slow.