Excessive Swap Memory Usage in MariaDB Server: Causes and Solutions?
I am currently experiencing an issue with my MariaDB server where it is excessively using swap memory, leading to significant performance degradation. I am not sure why the swap memory usage is so high, and I am worried about the impact of this "memory bomb" on my server's performance. Here are the details of my current setup and the steps I have taken so far:
Server Setup:
Database Server: MariaDB 10.11

Physical Memory (RAM): [used / total] 13 Gi / 15 Gi

Swap Space: [used / total] 5.7 Gi / 8.0 Gi

Operating System: Rocky Linux 8.8 (Green Obsidian)
Observations:

Excessive Swap Usage: The top command shows a high amount of swap memory usage.
enter image description here

Swap memory use (using /proc/$pid/status)
Name=mariadbd - Swap used: 5268960 KB

Current Memory Status (using SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Innodb_buffer_pool%';):
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data: 713855
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data: 11695800320
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty: 12714
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty: 208306176
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed: 17316310
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free: 1
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_not_young: 52897922
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_young: 11348673
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc: 0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_old: 263492

innodb local memory
max_connections | 5000
read_buffer_size | 131072
read_rnd_buffer_size | 262144
sort_buffer_size | 2097152
join_buffer_size | 262144
thread_stack  | 299008
Threads_connected | 981


Questions:
Why is my MariaDB server using so much swap memory?
Are there specific configurations or settings I should check or adjust to mitigate swap usage?
Could there be memory leaks or inefficient memory usage in my current setup?
What best practices should I follow to optimize memory usage and avoid swap memory dependency?

config
# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8mb3_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb3'
character-set-server = utf8mb3
innodb_buffer_pool_size=11G
skip-name-resolve
slow_query_log=ON
slow-query-log-file=/where/mysql-slow.log
log-error=/where/error.log
long_query_time=3
max_connections = 5000
log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id=####
max_binlog_size=100M
expire_logs_days=7
log-slave-updates=1
sql_mode = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
#
# * Galera-related settings
#
[galera]
wsrep_on=ON
binlog_format=row
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
datadir=/db/mysql
socket=/db/mysql/mysql.sock
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera-4/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://v-3,v-4,v-5,v-6,v-7"
wsrep_cluster_name='cluster'
wsrep_node_address='###.###.##.##'
wsrep_node_name='v-3'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth='1234'

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.11 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.11]


is the swap usage growing? Are large mounts of swap being swapped out? Is the MariaDB total usage saying about the same after a large amount of uptime? Which exact 10.11 version? I think there was a memory leak fixed at some stage.

5000 connections each having 3MB of buffers mean 15GB of RAM required for clients in the worst case. Can you show your config (wipe sensitive data in it)?

I've attached the configuration values.
I encountered an issue where reducing the number of connections resulted in clients being unable to establish connections. Could this issue be related to ProxySQL?

@이민수  Here is a similar case - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/256135/7895

Possible THP issue - fixed with MDEV-33279 in 10.11.7 or a few other fixed leaks.

I have a similar problem where swap usage grows steadily over time eventually causing performance degradation. If I then service mysql restart the swap space is returned, memory usage reset and the cycle starts over again. Can you post your figures after a db server restart? And how long it takes for those figures to return back to 5GB of used swap?

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size; --
I recommend 10G, but lower from there if swapping continues.
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';  --
Lower max_connections to perhaps 2000.
Lower the number of connections the app (or browser) tries make to MariaDB.

If the current status shows Threads_connected at 981, each with a 3MB buffer, this totals approximately 2.76GB. Could this be the reason for the increase in swap memory usage?

The 3MB is dubious.  But, yes, that is part of the problem.

@이민수 where do you see the 3MB buffer size?

@Kondybas - Over to you for the 3MB question.
