MySQL 8.0.39 - MySqlException (0x80004005): Out of memory;
We have a Windows Server 2022 with 56Gb RAM. This server is dedicated to MySQL DB and during idle it has ~50.9Gb available memory. But while bulk inserting rows (200k rows) into a table from an application I'm facing the following error. Unfortunately, application does not support batch inserts yet.
Message: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space 

Initially, I tried with default configuration then changed configuration after searching online for the issue and still facing the same error. As insertion query is executed, memory usage increases from ~4Gb to 55Gb+ with MySQL service consuming ~53Gb.
Following are the configurations set in my.ini
[mysqld]

default-storage-engine=INNODB

sql-mode="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

max_connections=200

thread_stack=100M

table_open_cache=10000

temptable_max_ram=5G

tmp_table_size=5G

internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine=TempTable

myisam_max_sort_file_size=2146435072

myisam_sort_buffer_size=6G

key_buffer_size=2048M

read_buffer_size=256M

read_rnd_buffer_size=512M

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

innodb_log_buffer_size=256M

innodb_buffer_pool_size=35G

innodb_redo_log_capacity=100M

innodb_thread_concurrency=13

innodb_autoextend_increment=64

innodb_buffer_pool_instances=16

innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000

innodb_old_blocks_time=1000

innodb_stats_on_metadata=0

innodb_file_per_table=1

innodb_checksum_algorithm=0

innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50

innodb_flush_method=normal

flush_time=300

join_buffer_size=256K

max_allowed_packet=1G

max_connect_errors=100

open_files_limit=10000

sort_buffer_size=4G

binlog_row_event_max_size=8K

sync_source_info=10000

sync_relay_log=10000

mysqlx_port=33060

upon checking online for solution, I increased innodb_buffer_pool_size and key_buffer_size . I also increased thread_stack size.
Please suggest If I'm missing any configuration or what configurations need to be adjusted to not get the error when bulk insert (~1M+ rows). Thanks.

Have you read the information from maysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/memory-use.html

key_buffer_size=2048M

If MyISAM isn't used massively you don't need key buffer such big. Nowadays 64-256MB is enough.
read_buffer_size=256M
read_rnd_buffer_size=512M
join_buffer_size=256K
sort_buffer_size=4G

That buffers are allocated for EACH of 200 connection you have allowed. Generally that values makes no sense. As of my experience 1-8MB for each parameter is quite enough. (8+8+8+8)*200=6.4GB instead of (256+512+4000+0.25)*200=960GB you have now.
Here is a more detailed explanation how RAM should be managed for MySQL
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/256135/7895

the linked homepage of mysql, explains everything in more detail
